# Why is this program giving me an infinite loop? Simple program

Tags: c

I was trying to make a simple program to change the base of a number (i,e I give the bases 2 and 5, and the number 101 and I should get 10) and when doing the function to read the bases I get the following: If I type in correctly the data it works, if I don't (for example, I type "231") the program goes into an infinite loop, why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int base1,base2;
    readBases(&base1,&base2);
    printf("%d%d\n",base1,base2);
    return 0;
}

void readBases(int *baseOrig, int * baseDest)
{
    int aux1,aux2,flag;
    do
    {
        printf("Type in the bases, in the format <a>b:");
        flag=scanf("<%d>%d",&aux1,&aux2);
        if(aux1<2||aux1>10||aux2<2||aux2>10)
        {
            flag=0;
            printf("Invalid data.\n");
        }
    }while(flag!=2);
    *baseOrig=aux1;
    *baseDest=aux2;
}
```

Comment: You must check the value of `flag` *before* examining the input values, but instead you ignore it and overwrite it.

Comment: When `scanf` can't convert the input, it goes back to where it left off. The erroneous input will stay in the queue and be parsed over and over again. I suggest that you read a whole line with `fgets` and then parse that with `sscanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand what you mean, before overwriting it, I should get into the "scanf" part, and assign a new value to it, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, the variables `aux1` and `aux2` are uninitialised. If `scanf()` fails to get the two `int` inputs, you are then into **undefined behaviour** by checking `aux1` and `aux2` before checking `flag`. You *must* check any function's status before processing its data.

Comment: I see, if I understood correctly, initializing aux1, aux2 at 0 in the beggining should fix it, although I tried and it didn't, am I missing somethink?

Comment: Please don't try to dodge checking the function return value, first. If it is not `2`, there is no point looking at `aux1` and `aux2`.

Comment: Pay attention to the comment by M Oehm.

Comment: Initialising the values to 0 will start you off with invalid values, which you then check. As Weather Vane said, check the function value first. If that is okay, you are guaranteed to have the two integers from the input in `aux1` and `aux2`, which you can then check for validity.

Comment: I don't understand what you guys mean by checking the function's return value, I think you're suggesting I add a "flag==2&&" in the condition of the if, but I don't understand why that would change anything. @FredK I tried, but I don't really understood what "the inputs will stay in the queue and be parsed over and over again" meant. 

I'm just a  beginner..

Comment: The concept is simple: First things first: Enforce the correct format first, the correct range of values after that. If there is a format error, the unconverted values have undefined values. That value might be the old value of the variable, but you can't be sure.

Comment: You can check that valid input was made by adding `flag` to your conditional expression: `if (flag!=2 || aux1<2 || aux1>10 || aux2<2 || aux2>10)` but that still does not address the first point made by @MOehm.

Comment: `scanf("<...` tries to read.  It gets `"231"` and as a `2` does not match `<`, `scanf()` returns 0 and the `2` stays in `stdin`.  Then code loops and tries again -  same result. - again and again.

Comment: After all you've said I tried to fix this by clearing the input buffer with "fflush(stdin);" before the scanf, but it still won't work, I was pretty sure that would fix it, why doesnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 flag=scanf("<%d>%d",&aux1,&aux2);
```

reads as much of the input stream as it can, and returns the number of converted fields.

If it can't read anything, then it will not progress input - getting stopped.  You need some way of reading the data - safely.

Line termination works quite well.

```
  while( fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer), stdin ) != NULL ){
       flag = sscanf( buffer, "<%d>%d",&aux1,&aux2);

  }
```